# Looping through array of object in Vuejs for HTML select tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I've a array of options which I have to iterate to show a select tag. Array of options looks likes this:

```
options: [
            {
                doctor: 'Doctor',
                engineer: 'Engineer',
                teacher: 'Teacher',
                other: 'Other'
            }
        ]
```

And the result should looks like this:

```
<select name="occupation">
    <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
    <option value="engineer">Engineer</option>
    <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Spangle Oh, ok understood. Thanks, I'll be thorough from the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        options: [
            {
                doctor: 'Doctor',
                engineer: 'Engineer',
                teacher: 'Teacher',
                other: 'Other'
            }
        ]
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select name="occupation">
    <option v-for="(option, index) in options[0]" :value="index">{{ option }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use v-for to iterate the items inside of your options

```
<select name="occupation">
    <option :value="name" v-for="(value, name) in options[0]" >{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

If your options contain only one element I prefer to just do it like this

```
options: {
       doctor: 'Doctor',
       engineer: 'Engineer',
       teacher: 'Teacher',
       other: 'Other'
 }
```

now you could call it like this below

```
<select name="occupation">
    <option :value="name" v-for="(value, name) in options" >{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

to know more list rendering  please read this docs [source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

Comment: `item` would give just the object. I need the `key` and the `value` of the object.

Comment: @AkhlakurRahman Considering you are getting free advice, maybe be a little more polite to those that are helping you as they do not have to, and you did not include any attempt to solve this yourself in your question.

Comment: @Qonvex620 Yeah, that would be much easier. But the data source is in this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="occupation">
    <option v-for="(value, key) in options[0]" v-bind: value="key">{{ value }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi @amit-maurya, perhaps offering a bit more explanation here would be good. What is this code doing? How does it work? These things are helpful in answers so that others can understand why this is a good solution.